# mysql and imported data in PDF::API2 .pdf file garbled

Tags: cjk

Using PDF::API2 I wrote a perl script to create an invoice PDF file with Japanese text.
The file encoding is utf8 and I have "use utf8" in the header.
If I declare the variables inside the script, everything is perfect.
However, if I get the variables data from my mysql database (also utf8), the PDF file shows garbled characters instead of Japanese.

Next, instead of the database, I tried with requiring a data.lib file (also utf8) that listed the variables.
Again, garbled characters.
It seems that the only way it works is when the variables are listed in the script itself, which makes it impossible to use for e.g. PDF files for separate customers, short of making the whole script for every customer again and again...
Is there a solution somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your cimment. I have a Japanese ttf added, and as long as the variable is declared INSIDE the script, everything is OK.

Comment: So, if the script ITSELF has: $last_name = "<JAPANESE>", it shows perfect Japanese characters. If I get the same variable from the database, like $last_name = $$hashref{last_name}, the Japanese is garbled. The same thing happens if I use a .lib file that says $last_name = "<JAPANESE>". I require the file (I also tried "do"), but the result is garbled. What is the difference between a variable inside the script and a variable from outside? Everything is utf-8.

Comment: I found the solution! Using Perl's Encode module, $last_name = decode("utf8", $$hashref{last_name}); (from mysql) or $last_name = decode("utf8", $last_name); (from .lib file)  will do the trick. I still don't understand why a hardcoded variable is OK and an "imported" variable is not, but as long as it is fixed.... Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! Using Perl's Encode module, $last_name = decode("utf8", $$hashref{last_name}); (from mysql) or $last_name = decode("utf8", $last_name); (from .lib file) will do the trick. I still don't understand why a hardcoded variable is OK and an "imported" variable is not, but as long as it is fixed....

Comment: needs some structure and visual styling